# Highlight portions of a phrase in body of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm attempting to find portions of a phrase in a body of text (using jQuery/JS), like the example below:

Phrase: In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.

Text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. **In the beginning** Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

It may not be the entire phrase, but simply a few words from the phrase.  Essentially I want to find sequences of words that match a portion of the original phrase.

I've done a lot of searching but have not come up with any ideas for this yet.

To further clarify: 
The user may input the phrase "In the beginning God created" and the text may ONLY say "God created". Nonetheless that "God created" should be highlighted because it matched part of the phrase the user entered.

Comment: Few words... well you need to know exactly how many before a script starts matching. 2, 3? What about the *exact order* or *at random*? Any script to share (the best one so-far)?

Comment: You need to give more precisions: what is the max size of the phrase (how many words)? Do you want to take the case, the punctuation in account?

Comment: What I know that, you must know exactly the portion that you want to highlight, then split the body string before and after of this portion, then enclose the portion with a `span` then rejoin the string again.

Comment: Adam, it's also important to know if your text contains HTML tags like `<a>`, `<b>`, `<i>` etc... in that case it becomes a lot complicated.

Comment: The text does contain HTML tags, but I would expect that none of the tags should be found within a matched string/phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**  *short code by using regex*

```js
function hilight(search) {
  if(search=="")return false;
  var sbody = document.getElementById('sbody').innerHTML;
  sbody = sbody.replace(/<b class="hilight">([^<]+)<\/b>/gmi, '$1');  // remove previous hilighted text
  var re = new RegExp('\\b(' + search + ')\\b', 'gmi');
  // var re = '/\b(' + search + ')\b/gmi';
  subst = '<b class="hilight">$1</b>';
  var result = sbody.replace(re, subst);
  document.getElementById('sbody').innerHTML = result
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" onkeyup="return hilight(this.value);" />

<div id="sbody">
  I'm attempting to find portions of a phrase in a body of text Nonetheless
  that "God created" should be highlighted because it matched part of the phrase the user entered.
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, very impressive.  Thank you!

Comment: @Adam: It doesn't even implement the second half of the requirement. Not sure why you accept and bounty this answer.

Comment: Why do you say that? Seems to do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I'd so something like this:

```
var minNumberOfWordsInSequence = 3;
var phrase = "In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.";
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. In the beginning Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

var phrasesToCheck = [];

phrase.split(' ').forEach(function(word, idx, words) {
    if (words.length > (idx + minNumberOfWordsInSequence - 1)) {
        var segment = "";
        for (var c = 0; c < minNumberOfWordsInSequence; c++) {
            segment += words[idx + c] + " ";
        }
        phrasesToCheck.push(segment.trim());
    }
});

phrasesToCheck.forEach(function(phrase) {
    if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(phrase.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        console.log("Found '" + phrase.toLowerCase() + "' in the text.");
    }
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle to play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/remus/mgv6mvwn/

You could condense this a fair bit, but I'll leave it like this for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this let's you decide whether you want to search for a whole phrase or every single word in your search phrase, like you asked for. It will then output the searched and highlighted text in a div below the original text, or you can change it to output instead of the original text by changing this line: Please see OPTIONS below the code for usage.

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = Text;
```

to

```
document.getElementById('searchtext').innerHTML = Text;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vr7cvcwe/1)

HTML:

```
    <div id="searchtext">


I'm attempting to find portions of a phrase in a body of text (using jQuery/JS), like the example below:

Phrase: In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.

Text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. In the beginning Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

It may not be the entire phrase, but simply a few words from the phrase. Essentially I want to find sequences of words that match a portion of the original phrase.

I've done a lot of searching but have not come up with any ideas for this yet.

To further clarify: The user may input the phrase "In the beginning God created" and the text may ONLY say "God created". Nonetheless that "God created" should be highlighted because it matched part of the phrase the user entered.

</div>
<div id="output" style="margin-top:40px;"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
function HighlightText(bodyText, searchTerm) 
{

    highlightStartTag = "<font style='font-weight:bold;'>";
    highlightEndTag = "</font>";


  var newText = "";
  var i = -1;
  var lcSearchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
  var lcBodyText = bodyText.toLowerCase();

  while (bodyText.length > 0) {
    i = lcBodyText.indexOf(lcSearchTerm, i+1);
    if (i < 0) {
      newText += bodyText;
      bodyText = "";
    } else {

      if (bodyText.lastIndexOf(">", i) >= bodyText.lastIndexOf("<", i)) {

        if (lcBodyText.lastIndexOf("/script>", i) >= lcBodyText.lastIndexOf("<script", i)) {
          newText += bodyText.substring(0, i) + highlightStartTag + bodyText.substr(i, searchTerm.length) + highlightEndTag;
          bodyText = bodyText.substr(i + searchTerm.length);
          lcBodyText = bodyText.toLowerCase();
          i = -1;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return newText;
}


function highlight(searchPhrase, treatAsPhrase,element)
{
  if (treatAsPhrase) {
    searchArray = [searchPhrase];
  } else {
    searchArray = searchPhrase.split(" ");
  }

  var Text = document.getElementById(element).innerHTML;
  for (var i = 0; i < searchArray.length; i++) {
    Text = HighlightText(Text, searchArray[i]);
  }

  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = Text;
  return true;
}

highlight('Afterwards God created',0,'searchtext')
```

**OPTIONS:**

```
                                              \/ element that should be searched, see the DEMO
highlight('Afterwards God created',0,'searchtext')
                    ^searchPhrase  ^handle as phrase (1) or search for every single word (0)
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** you need to decompose the search-text into constituent words - in an ordered list.
*Ignoring problems of multiple white space or punctuation marks*
this could be simplistically done using split:

var search_str =  "In the beginning God created"

var list = search_str.split()

**Second** you need to use the list to generate the combinations of words you want to match.

list[1]**,** list[2]**,** list[3], ...

list[1]+" "+list[2]**,** list[2]+" "+list[3]**,** list[3]+" "+list[4], ...

list[1]+" "+list[2]+" "+list[3]**,** list[2]+" "+list[3]+" "+list[4]**,** list[3]+" "+list[4]+" "+list[5], ...

etc

It's quite possible - but messy to program such stuff.
I am not going to try here.

Later you'd need to look at RegExp's to allow for long white spaces and for punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

An approach of creating a regex by splitting the search text on whitespace might work.

The search phrase `"In the beginning"` can be transformed into the regex:

```
/(\b(In|the|beginning)\b([^\w<>]|(?=<))+)+/gi
```

The `[^\w<>]` is to consume non-word characters but not HTML tag delimiters. The `|(?=<)` is so it will also match (but not connsume) the beginning of an opening or closing HTML tag.

HTML:

```
<input id="search" type="text">
<span id="match" style="color: red;"></span>
<p id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea <b>commodo</b> consequat. In the <i>beginning</i> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var _search = document.getElementById('search'),
    _text = document.getElementById('text'),
    _match = document.getElementById('match'),
    body = _text.innerHTML;

_match.parentElement.removeChild(_match);
_match.removeAttribute('id');

function onSearchInput(event) {
    var query = _search.value.trim(),
        rxStr = query.replace(/\s+/g, '|'),
        newBody = '',
        lastIndex = 0,
        result,
        rx;
    if (!rxStr) {
        _text.innerHTML = body;
        return;
    }
    rx = new RegExp('(\\b(' + rxStr + ')\\b([^\\w<>]|(?=<))+)+', 'ig');
    result = rx.exec(body);
    if (!result) {
        return;
    }
    console.log('rx:', rx.source);
    while (result) {
        console.log('match:', result[0]);
        newBody += body.slice(lastIndex, result.index);
        _match.textContent = result[0];
        newBody += _match.outerHTML;
        lastIndex = result.index + result[0].length;
        result = rx.exec(body);
    }
    newBody += body.slice(lastIndex);
    _text.innerHTML = newBody;
}

_search.addEventListener('input', onSearchInput);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ta80a9h2/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var div = $("div") // element containing `text`
        , input = $("#input")
        , highlighted = $("<span class=word>").css("fontWeight", "bold");

    input.on({
      change: function (e) {
        var m = div.text().match(new RegExp(e.target.value, "i"));
        if (m !== null) {
            div.html(function (_, text) {
                return text.replace(highlighted[0].outerHTML, highlighted.text())
                       .replace(m[0], highlighted.text(m[0])[0].outerHTML)
            });
        } 
      }
    });
```

```js
var div = $("div") // element containing `text`
        , input = $("#input")
        , highlighted = $("<span class=word>").css("fontWeight", "bold");
    
    input.on({
      change: function (e) {
        var m = div.text().match(new RegExp(e.target.value, "i"));
        if (m !== null) {
            div.html(function (_, text) {
                return text.replace(highlighted[0].outerHTML, highlighted.text())
                       .replace(m[0], highlighted.text(m[0])[0].outerHTML)
            });
        } 
      }
      // clear `input`
      , focus:function(e) {
          e.target.value = ""
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" />
<br />
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. In the beginning Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <div>
```

Answer (score -1):

<strike>I'm not certain what you're asking from the original post, but</strike> assuming you know the sequence you are looking for you can use the `indexOf()` method to return a given value's position within a string.

Comment: The question (is not only incomplete) but it also states that a search query might be longer than an indexOf() might partial-match a string. Or you could add more to your answer? (You're in the good direction more or less.)

Comment: Having re-read the question, you're correct - that said, given no best effort/code example was provided I'm still inclined to offer only a starting point.

Comment: A starting point is all expect, however, I don't know the exact sequence.  For example, the user may input the phrase "In the beginning God created" and the text may ONLy say "God created". Nonetheless that "God created" should be highlighted because it matched part of the phrase the user entered.